# Get my querybuilder result from my QuizRepository to my QuizController

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, doctrine

I'm very new in both code & Symfony, i needed to do a `<select>` for my quiz that list all my theme (category)
So in my QuizRepository i did this :

```
public function byTheme()
{
    $qB = $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
               ->select('theme')
               ->distinct()
               ->getQuery()
               ->getResult()
           ;
}
```

But now, how can i call my result (here `$qB` right?) into my QuizController

i tried this, but i'm sure this is far far from what i should do :

```
$response = $this->forward('App\Repository\QuizRepository::select');

return $response
```

Comment: What **exactly** are you looking for? Why not return something from the `byTheme`  method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to return the result instead of storing it in a local variable:

```
public function byTheme()
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('q')
               ->select('theme')
               ->distinct()
               ->getQuery()
               ->getResult()
           ;
}
```

Afterwards you can call the method as so in your controller:

```
public function yourAction(QuizRepository $repository)
{
    $quizzes = $repository->byTheme();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i know it must seem so stupid to ask for something that easy , but i really tried..

Comment: Don't worry and keep learning :) Always check the documentation. They have some pretty examples: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository